# how can i calculate mean by groups without outliers?

Tags: r

I have data of two groups, for example

```
> data.frame(group=rep(1:2,each=4),value=c(102,104,107,45,204,199,217,77))

  group value
1     1   102
2     1   104
3     1   107
4     1    45
5     2   204
6     2   199
7     2   217
8     2    77
```

and i´d like to obtain the mean of both groups without outliers (mean of group 1 for values > 50 and mean of group 2 for values > 100)

Answer (score 2):

Get the data:

```
test <- data.frame(group=rep(1:2,each=4),value=c(102,104,107,45,204,199,217,77))
```

A fairly extendable solution using `by` and `switch`:

```
by(test,test$group,
    function(x) {
        switch(
            x$group[1],
            #group 1
            mean(x$value[x$value > 50]),
            #group 2
            mean(x$value[x$value > 100])
        )
    }
)
```

Result:

```
test$group: 1
[1] 104.3333
------------------------------------------------------------ 
test$group: 2
[1] 206.6667
```